# How to execute SonarQube Runner from Bamboo?

Tags: azure, sonarqube, bamboo, sonar-runner, sonarqube-5.4

I have setup SonarQube in Azure Virtual Machine.

sonarqube-5.4

MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner-2.0

SonarQube website at 9000 port is up and running.

(http://something.regionname.cloudapp.azure.com:9000/)

Now, how to execute sonarrunner from a local bamboo build server ?

What are the configuration settings and other changes ?

Earlier, I did setup sonarqube with bamboo locally successfully, because all are local paths.

But now, I want to install sonarqube and bamboo on different servers. How to connect these two ?

Please provide comments / settings in detail.

Thanks

Bhanu.

Answer (score 2):

There's a Bamboo plugin for that: https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.marvelution.bamboo.plugins.sonar.tasks/server/overview

I haven't used it, and I don't know whether it supports SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild (I'm skeptical on that count.)

Perhaps your best bet is to treat Bamboo like a fancy CLI, and use follow the [instructions for analyzing from the command line](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/From+the+Command+Line). I.E.

1. install an configure SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild on the Bamboo server
2. via Bamboo run commands:

   1. `MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe begin /k:"sonarqube_project_key" /n:"sonarqube_project_name" /v:"sonarqube_project_version"`
   2. build the project
   3. `MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe end`

Comment: this plugin is unsupported. _This add-on isn't formally supported, but you can ask a question via Atlassian Answers._

Answer (score 1):

Mibex Software's excellent free [Sonar for Bamboo](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/ch.mibex.bamboo.sonar4bamboo/server/overview) has evolved to be the canonical (and supported) SonarQube integration for Bamboo - it provides a *Bamboo tasks to analyze projects with Sonar for Maven, Gradle & SonarRunner* and also *supports auto-branching for Sonar-based code reviews*-

Comment: It is worth noting - that this plugin is not free.

Answer (score -1):

The bamboo server has Sonar Runner task that can be used to execute the code.
You need to have sonar-project.properties file in your root folder.

The settings that need to be done are:

```
sonar.projectKey=<projectkey>
sonar.projectName=<projectname>
sonar.projectVersion=1.0.0
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
# Enable the Visual Studio bootstrapper
sonar.visualstudio.enable=true
# Code Coverage
#placeholder-for-modular-coverage-reporting
# Unit Test Results
#placeholder-for-modular-unit-test-reporting
# Required only when using SonarQube < 4.2
sonar.language=cs
# FXCop
# This property is set because it is required by the SonarQube Runner.
# But it is not taken into account because the location of the source
# code is retrieved from the .sln and .csproj files.
sonar.sources=.
# If you have multiple solution files then use the current one by setting up the below property
sonar.visualstudio.outputPaths=
# Test projects can be imported as unit test code (which is not analyzed by coding rules) using the regular expression property
#sonar.visualstudio.testProjectPattern=
#sonar.visualstudio.solution=YourSolution.sln
sonar.visualstudio.skipIfNotBuilt=true
```

This [Msbuild Sonar](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+MSBuild) may be helpful for you.